Why pointer precedence in while loop is working differently?
*s++ evalutes right to left .
while loop inside main is evaluting as right to left but while loop outside main is working as it has precedence left to rigth why???
int main(void) {
    char* s = "hello world";  
    char* p;
    str_cpy(p, s);
    printf("%s\n", p); // prints --> hello world 
    while(*s++) { // *s++ is working as *(s++) 
        printf("%c", *s); // prints --> ello world skips the 'h' character
    }
    return 0;
}

void str_cpy(char* p, char* s) {
     while(*p++ = *s++); //*s++ is working as (*s)++ 
}


It works just the same, but you forget that s is incremented as part of the *s++ expression, and so you will always skip the first character in the loop. I recommend you explain it in great detail to a rubber duck, it might help you understand.

Yes But it's not skipping in second loop why

Because if the second loop you are referring to *s once. If the first loop you somehow think that the second *s inside the loop must be the *s that it was before the *s++.

By the way, your code is worse than I thought... When you do str_cpy(p, s), where does p point?

If it was (*s)++ then it would increment the char value, which is not what happens here.

You don't have a clear understanding of what's going on with while(*s++) ... printf("%c", *s); because in while(*s++) there is too much going on for your mind to grasp - literally.  Human brains are very limited in how many things they can keep track of at any one time - and in there's quite a bit going on all in the space of four characters - *s++.  the pointer is dereferenced, that value is extracted, compared to zero, the pointer incremented, and the loop entered - or not - depending on the comparison to zero.  In other words - too much for a human brain.  It's bad code.

(cont) It's an "idiom" from fifty years ago when cramming as much code as possible into a line was done because input was often done on punch cards.  And when lead was used in paint and gasoline.

Perhaps the biggest problem with this code is that p is uninitialized, but you're using it as your target pointer when calling str_cpy.  That's a severe bug, and undefined behavior.  Hint:  Always define your pointers before trying to use them.  Where are you expecting the result of the string copy to be stored?

Postfix ++ has higher precedence than unary *, so *s++ is parsed as *(s++).
So you're dereferencing the result of s++, which is the current value of s, and then at some point s is incremented.  It's logically equivalent to:
t0 <- s
t1 <- *t0
s <- s + 1

with the caveat that the last two operations can happen in any order, even simultaneously.
This works the same way in both while loops; in the first loop you're testing the result of *s and in the second you're testing the result of *p = *s.
The = operator doesn't force a sequence point and the side effect of ++ doesn't have to be applied immediately after evaluation, so p does not have to be incremented before *s++ is evaluated:
t0 <- p
t1 <- s
*t0 <- *t1
s <- s + 1
t <- t + 1

The last three operations can be evaluated in any order.  C does not force left-to-right evaluation on assignment, so it's possible for *s++ to be evaluated before *p++.
Edit
And as Tom points out, you haven't set p to point to anything; if this code works at all it's by accident.  Remember p doesn't store the string contents, it stores the address of the buffer where the string lives.  Until you initialize it p's value is indeterminate and could point literally anywhere, which may or may not be writable and may or may not already be storing something important.
You'll either need to allocate memory for string at runtime and set p to point to it:
char *p = calloc(strlen(s) + 1, sizeof *p);

which will need to be deallocated when you're done:
free(p); // last thing before the return statement

or you'll need to declare it as an array large enough to hold the string:
char p[12] = {0};

or
char p[strlen(s) + 1];
memset(p, 0, sizeof p);

The second array is a variable length array whose size isn't known until runtime, so it can't have an initializer like the fixed-size example.  When dealing with strings it's often a good idea to make sure your target buffer is zeroed out.

OP's code never defines p, so it's undefined behavior.

Lets rewrite the loops with labels and goto...
The first loop will be something like this:
while_condition:
    {
        char temp = *s;
        s = s + 1;  // Here s is increased

        if (temp == '\0')
        {
            goto while_end;
        }
    }
while_body:
    {
        printf("%c", *s);
    }
    goto while_condition;
while_end:

As you can see the increment of s is part of the condition, so when you print *s you will never have the first character of the string.
Now we do the second loop:
while_condition:
    {
        char temp1 = *p;
        char temp2 = *s;

        *p = *s;

        p = p + 1;
        s = s + 1;

        if (temp2 == '\0')
        {
            goto while_end;
        }
    }
while_body:
    {
        // Empty
    }
    goto while_condition;
while_end:

This should hopefully make the different clear.

i want to know that if  *p++ evalutes right to left then how first char of s is copied in p inside a str_cpy  function ? Because when i execute *s++ it prints second char of string "hello world"

@AdityaPatel You never defined p, so your posted code is undefined behavior.  You could easily get a segmentation fault.

For starters the pointer p does not initialised and point to  point to a  vali object of an array type
char* p;

So the function call
str_cpy(p, s);

involes undefined behavior.
As for your question then this expression
*s++

contains two operators: the postfix increment operator ++ and the unary indirection operator *. Postfix operators have a higher precedence than unary operators.  Thus the above expression is equivalent to the following expression
*(s++)

Now let's determine what is the value of the postfix increment operator ++. According to the C23 Standard (6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators)

2 The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand.
As a side effect, the value of the operand object is incremented (that
is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to it).

So according to the quote the expression s++ yields the value of the pointer s before incrementing the pointer itself.
Knowing that it is easy to determine what happens in this while loop
while(*s++) { // *s++ is working as *(s++) 
    printf("%c", *s); // prints --> ello world skips the 'h' character
}

In the condition of the while loop there is checked the character of the current value of the pointer. As a side effect the pointer is incremented. So within the body of the while loop we have the pointer after its increment. As a result this statement
    printf("%c", *s); // prints --> ello world skips the 'h' character

outputs the character pointed to by the already incremented pointer within the condition of the while loop. That is within the condition of the while loop and inside the body of the while loop there are dereferenced different values of the pointer.
The while loop can be equivalently rewritten the following way
while(*s) {
    ++s;
    printf("%c", *s);
}

If you want to get a similar effect as in the while loop within the function str_cpy then you can write for example
while(*s) {
    printf("%c", *s++);
}


Add printf("%c", *s); to the body of the while loop in str_cpy and you will see that the behavior is the same.
As some programmer dude pointed out, p does not point to valid memory.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void str_cpy(char* p, char* s) {
     while((*p++ = *s++)) {
        printf("%c", *s); // prints --> ello world skips the 'h' character
     }
}

int main(void) {
    char* s = "hello world";
    char* p = malloc ( 12);
    str_cpy(p, s);
    printf("\n\n%s\n\n", p); // prints --> hello world
    while(*s++) {
        printf("%c", *s); // prints --> ello world skips the 'h' character
    }
    free ( p);
    return 0;
}

